Out of date FIDE rating question/answers
There are many old questions about FIDE ratings that are now misleading.
If we edited them all, they would fill the front page for well over a week.
Many of them stil contains useful content, so a delete does not seem like an good option.
I don't know if this site has a system for locking/closing historical questions.

Care to share the links?

@SecretAgentMan 2 that I edited this week.  https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/32673/why-was-initial-rating-of-fide-calculated-that-strangely  https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/39204/what-was-the-justification-for-calculations-of-fide-unrated-player-having-differ
